# Molecular level Fallout 4 bug - only showing one piece

Tags: fallout-4, xbox-one

I've played this game with 4 different characters that go up to level 85+ and i just ran into a unique problem.

When im in workshop mode in Sanctuary trying to build the molecular beam i only have one piece of the machine available to build.  STABLIZED REFLECTOR PLATFORM. The other pieces simply aren't there in the special section. I have the artillery piece, robot workbench, and then the stablized reflector platform. That's all.

So weird and so frustrating.

I disabled all the mods and went back to the Glowing Sea mission and worked my way back to molecular level and the problem persists.

Comment: Have you actually built the platform yet? What is your current objective? Based on what you've written, it doesn't actually look like anything is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the base first, then the quest will update and you'll have to go back and talk to your assisting NPC to get the ability to build the other pieces.